# Handling large arrays

Tags: c++

I am creating a battleship which has a 10x10 grid and I would like each part to represented by part of an array, is there any way in which I can have each representing one number from one to 100 without writing

`grid[100] = {1, 2, 3, 4 //... and so on.`?

Comment: Use a `for()` loop to fill in the array with sequential numbers.

Comment: Use a loop to initialize it?

Comment: The algorithmic way to do this is with [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota)

Comment: @drescherjm It's small in memory, but large enough that you wouldn't want to have to type the contents by hand in the program.

Comment: Er, *why* would one need an array with consecutive numbers? `grid[n]` will always be `n` (or `n+1`).

Comment: @Biffen Good point. The question is obviously about some XY problem. An array doesn't seem to be necessary at all.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to implement this would be to use any kind of loop to iterate through the elements in the given array (grid[x]).

You could simply use a for-loop, implemented like this:

```
for (int i  = 0; i < grid.size(); i++) {
    grid[i] = i
}
```

The most gallant way to do this is to put the code inside your constructor (if you have one in your class), thus initializing the grid each time you start the battleship.